# Jasper : Compiling same jrxml file into multiple output formats

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am doing a POC with following requirement:

I have two tables A and B in a database having same columns and column types.

I am running the following query to get the differences between the two table viz. same key, different columns or row existing in one but not in another:

```
 SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
 FROM
 (
 SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, ...
 FROM A
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3, ...
 FROM B
) as tmp
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Once I get the difference rows in Java collection, I want to output them as a report.

However, the requirement is that the output format should be configurable. For e.g. if the requirement is to generate PDF, output should be PDF. If the requirement is XLS, the output should be XLS.

Now, I am exploring the possibility of generating a single JRXML file and compiling the same JRXML into a PDF or a XLS.

Is it possible ? Can anyone please point me to a example where same JRXML is compiled into multiple output formats.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you try anything? Any luck?

Comment: So? More or less the 3 answered the same... Yes, it is possible.Is any problem now?

Comment: @Anto: Yes.. I tried the way answers were and it worked. Thanks..

Comment: @DownVoter: Pls explain the downvote... if its for not commenting earlier... it was because was out on weekend and could try only today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You must to write your jrxml and compile into jasper file. Then, when you have your JasperPrint, you can ask to build a PDF file (**JRPdfExporter**):

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream fillPDF(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws Exception{
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
     exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
     exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,baos); 
     exporter.exportReport(); 
     return baos;
}
```

Or a XLS file (**JRXlsExporter**):

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream fillXLS(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws Exception{
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     JRXlsExporter exporterXls = new JRXlsExporter();
     exporterXls.setParameter( JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint );
     exporterXls.setParameter( JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
     exporterXls.exportReport(); 
     exporterXlsbaos;
}
```

Note: for simply, I have repeat the code, but you can write one method and a parameter with the type of report. Also, you can handle the Exceptions correctly.

Comment: mhhhhhhh... it seems to be a typo, because it can't be a method... This was more than 2 years ago, I don't really remember this line :?!

Anyway, I remember that the code was working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is possible. I had a requirement to implement a single method to generate the report in both formats. And i've actually split the format of the output part in two different methods (just for my ease of use :) ). So basically you can create two methods (in case of just the pdf and xls formats) and call them based on your requirement (you can also put everything inside a single method, but you'll have to use some controls in that case. In my case, the responsible parts in my methods would be:

```
        public void generatePDF(JasperPrint print) throws FileNotFoundException, JRException,
                                                                           IOException {
        ///// For printing report as PDF file ////////
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss");
        String now = ft.format(date);
        String new_name = now + ".pdf";
        OutputStream out = null;
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/" + new_name));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, out);
        out.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
}
```

and

```
    public void generateEXCEL(JasperPrint print) throws FileNotFoundException, JRException,
                                                                         IOException {
    //--------------EXCEL---------------
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss");
    String now = ft.format(date);
    String excel = now + ".xls";
    OutputStream out2 = null;
    out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File("/" + excel));
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // coding For Excel:
    JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, byteArrayOutputStream2);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.exportReport();
    out2.write(byteArrayOutputStream2.toByteArray());
    out2.flush();
    out2.close();}
```

In this case i'm saving the generated output in the ***root*** directory of the OS filesystem (that's why of the "/").

While inside the method calling these two, there is a single jrxml read:

```
    JasperPrint print = null;
                try {
                    print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(template, parameters, conn);
}
    ........
    generatePDF(print);
    generateXLS(print);
```

Note: In the case of a .xls output, some formatting is required. This can be done using some specific parameters (just like in the above case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,filename);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(filename);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToXml(jasperPrint);
```

These are different formats you can use.